# How to create Daemon for celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

I try to create daemon for celery.

This is my Celeryd

```
# Name of nodes to start, here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="w1"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/ubuntu/workspace/ward/www“
ENV_PYTHON=“/usr/bin/python3”

# How to call "manage.py celeryd_multi"
CELERYD_MULTI="python3 $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryd_multi"

# How to call "manage.py celeryctl"
CELERYCTL="python3 $CELERYD_CHDIR/manage.py celeryctl"

# Extra arguments to celeryd
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=2 --beat --events --loglevel=info"

# Name of the celery config module.
CELERY_CONFIG_MODULE="celeryconfig"

# %n will be replaced with the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/logs/celery/%n.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER=“ubuntu”
CELERYD_GROUP=“ubuntu”

# Name of the projects settings module.
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=“fb_archive.settings"
```

It doesn't have any errors.
But my django project couldn't use celery.

If I run this code, `celery --app=fb_archive.celery:app worker -B --loglevel=INFO`, the django project could use celery.

Comment: What does it (webserver/django/celery) write in logs?

Comment: @1844144, It doesn't have any logs. It's blank.

Comment: we can continue in the chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97075/chat-with-egaoneko

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
# Names of nodes to start
#   most people will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="worker"
#   but you can also start multiple and configure settings
#   for each in CELERYD_OPTS (see `celery multi --help` for examples):
#CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"
#   alternatively, you can specify the number of nodes to start:
#CELERYD_NODES=10

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="fb_archive.celery:app"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/ubuntu/workspace/ward/www"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8 --loglevel=info"

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%N.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists, e.g. nobody).
CELERYD_USER="root"
CELERYD_GROUP="root"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

It's work!

Comment: please help others in a similar situation by describing what was wrong, and what fixed it and why